# Ruby - GCC's dependency file parsing optimisation

Tags: ruby, parsing, gcc

I am looking for optimisation ideas regarding the below piece of code written in Ruby. It looks for header file dependencies in a dependency file (generated by GCC using `gcc -M -MM -MF`)

I've ran the Ruby profiler and found that most of the CPU time was spent in the Array#each function below.

```
lines = File.readlines(depends_file)
lines.each do |line|
  if line.include?(".h") then
    line.lstrip.rstrip.chomp("\\").split(' ').each do |line|
      header_dependencies << line
    end
  end
end
```

The depends file contains dependencies in the makefile rule format as specified by gcc's -M option, see [GCC's Preprocessor Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). Here's an example from my project -

```
CyclicRedundancyCheck.o: src/CyclicRedundancyCheck.c \
 inc/CyclicRedundancyCheck.h inc/StdDefs.h
```

Can someone please post an alternate, heavily optimised solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not heavily optimized but a bit faster here (about 20% for my test-case):

```
File.open(depends_file, 'r') do | io |
  io.each do |line|
    next unless line.include?('.h')
    header_dependencies.concat(line.split)
  end
end
header_dependencies.delete('\\')
```

I don't think you can gain much more with Ruby itself. If this is really too slow, you should consider programming it (partly) in C (as an extension).

Note also that the approach is far from being robust. E.g.

```
 foo.o: src/ext.hlib/foo.c \
```

will wrongly be matched. Making it more robust will most likely cost performance, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although it isn't giving me the performance boost I had hoped for, it is a more elegant solution than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

A Regex based solution is a touch faster (about 5%) than @undur_gongor's solution.

```
header_dependencies = Set.new
lines = File.readlines(depends_file)
lines.each do |line|
  header = line.match('[\w\/-]+\.h')
  header_dependencies.add(header.to_s) unless header.nil?
end
```

It suffers the same flaw as @undur_gongor mentioned but that's something I can live with.